# Running iOS Apps on Flash

Tags: iphone, ios, flash, ipad

I wrote an app for iOS on iPhone and iPad. I would like to make the app (a children's game) I wrote available on my website through Flash. I don't know if this is possible...

Would I just have to write the application in another language? I can't find any tools that would help me make it available.

Comment: What language did you write your iOS app in?

Comment: I wrote my apps in Objective C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no tools to make an iOS application run through Flash Player.

Probably your best bet on writing an application that will run as a native app and within the web is to pursue writing a web application optimized for smartphones.  This way you could use a UIWebView to run it within a native application (and thus still have it in the App Store) but also make it available via the web.  You could even consider leveraging tools like Phonegap to help with this.  But of course this means re-writing your application.

Comment: The upcoming trend will be writing apps in HTML5, which can support cross platform, and with future release function and when more browser upgrade themself to support HTML5 function, it would be one of the most powerful app builder around.

Answer (score 2):

If you wrote your app in HTML5, then you can make it available to your website, but if written with obj C, I highly doubt there is any easy way out solution beside re-write the app in another language.